# How do I run a script in the command line that is saved in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I don't know how to run any code I write. If its a simple practice problem that just spits out output values then of course it works, but when I practice something I would actually use like a web scraper that requires a google search input I don't know how run it so it can accept an input. This specific example is from 'automate the boring stuff' chapter 11 'I'm feeling lucky' google search problem.  I work out of jupyter notebook and research suggests that I need to run my code in the command line. If my file name is 'Google', what do I type into the command line to make this work if I am for example want to search for the word 'dog'? I've look all over the internet for answers and can't seem to find them, most likely because the explanation is going over my head. Any help is appreciated.

```
#! python3
#Opens several Google search results.
import os
import requests, sys, webbrowser, bs4
import os

print('Googling...')

res =requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + 'Soup'.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

soup =bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

linkElems = soup.select('.r a')

numOpen = min(5, len(linkElems))

for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com' + linkElems[i].get('href'))
```

There is no error message when I run the script in my jupyter notebook. It just prints 'Googling...' as expected, but does not allow for a google search input.

Comment: I have heard of (on the *talk python to me* podcast I think) different 3rd party packages that allow you to run notebooks in command line but I've never tried them. Perhaps this could help you achieve what you want. This [blog](http://deeplearning.lipingyang.org/2018/03/28/run-jupyter-notebook-script-from-terminal/) mentions one of the packages I heard of. If you've already seen these solutions and they didn't work then my sincere apologies

Comment: It didn't work. All I am trying to do is run a basic script and I can't get anything to communicate with each other. I download the file as a .py file and that doesn't work either because I don't know how to change the file path.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: Sorry to hear it didn't work. You should be able to change file paths directly on your OS or using python `os` or `pathlib` modules. Why don't you just use [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/)? I mean you can easily run the code cell by cell just like in Jupyter Notebook. I mean sure you won't have all outputs glaring at you but you have the `variable explorer` tab.